# How to output the number from Excel as a String in java?

Tags: java, file

This is my code, which reading from excell file and insert to database, but when I insert to database numeric type from excell, it looks like this 9.94775287264E11, but I want to store this data like this 994775287264. This number value in excell store like this 994775287264

```
public static Response acceptFile(File file) {
        try {
            String phoneNumber = "";
            String textMessage = "";
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                    //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        phoneNumber = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }

                }

            }
            insertExcellFileToDb(phoneNumber, textMessage);
            System.out.println(phoneNumber + " " + textMessage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How are you effectively storing the data in the database? In the snipped you provided both `phoneNumber` and `textMessage` are strings, but somewhere they are being converted to numbers. Maybe in `insertExcellFileToDb`?

Comment: Why not just call getStringCellValue() ?

Comment: @Picoral in my database phone_column type String, so I just want to store it as true way, not only weird.

Comment: I solved already which using the following code
phoneNumber =  NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());

Comment: Hi @AnarMəmmədov. Great that you solved your problem. Could you please post an answer to your own question, marking it as a the solution, containing an explanation as to how you solved this as well as including the updated code? This would be good documentation for anyone having this problem in the future.

Comment: @tjheslin1 I explain my own question!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I've change the code to the following code:

```
if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
   phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
} else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
   textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
}
```